# Beautiful Soup Issue- Can't Find the correct Issue

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am having trouble with Beautiful Soup. I am trying to scrape Kayak, but when I print the length of the find_all it is returning 0. I am using selenium in conjunction with Beautiful Soup as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


## Kayak URL
origin = "PIT"
destination = "ARN"
startdate = "2022-12-18"

url = "https://www.kayak.com/flights/" + origin + "-" + destination + "/" +\
      startdate + "?sort=price_a "

## Setting Up Webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
print(len(soup.find_all("span", attrs={'class': 'depart-time base-time'})))

deptimes = soup.find_all("span", attrs={'class': 'depart-time base-time'})
arrtimes = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'arrival-time base-time'})
meridies = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'time-meridiem meridiem'})
```

This is what I am trying to take from the kayak website.

```
<span class="depart-time base-time">12:45 </span>
```

Comment: Thats likely because the content is rendered on kayak via Javascript so when you hit it with BeautifulSoup, the content has not rendered yet.  You can use something like selenium in partnership with BS to do what you want

Comment: @terpinmd I updated my code above to include my selenium code from my script.

Comment: Better add your whole code, it will be easy for us to reproduce it and help you.

Comment: @MeT Just added it!

Answer (score 0):

With **playwright** python you can do something like this, it will be very similar with selenium.
You need to select each **box of flight** and after iterate each element extracting data that you want.
Here you have an example:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)

    ## Kayak URL
    origin = "PIT"
    destination = "ARN"
    startdate = "2022-12-18"
    url = "https://www.kayak.com/flights/" + origin + "-" + destination + "/" + \
          startdate + "?sort=price_a "
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(url)
    
    #select all boxes of each flight
    allFlight = page.query_selector_all(".resultInner")
    #extract data from each flight
    for index, flight in enumerate(allFlight, start=1):
        print("Flight nº: "+str(index))
        print("From " + flight.query_selector(".depart-time").inner_text()
              + flight.query_selector(".depart-time+span").inner_text()
              + " To " + flight.query_selector(".arrival-time").inner_text()
              + flight.query_selector(".arrival-time+span").inner_text())
        print("Flight companies:  " + flight.query_selector(".section.times .bottom,.multi-airline-names").inner_text().strip())
   
    browser.close()
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Here you have  [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) documentation.
I hope i was able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, the issue lies in that Kayak is detecting it. Every time I try to move forward with it, I get re-directed to this link: https://www.kayak.com/help/bots.html

Comment: With selenium or with playwright?